# How to send WebPush with payload to 100000 plus users at a time

Tags: php, push-notification

I am using PHP to send push notification to browsers using VAPID. I am using web push library to achieve this (https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php) and it is working fine for me. 
But issue is sending push notification to 100000+ users is time consuming and also it slow down the server.

How can I send notification to multiple users at a time or send notification to 1000 users at a time using one API call? Any help will be appreciated

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
use Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush;
$subscription = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$auth = array(
    'VAPID' => array(
        'subject' => 'https://www.example.com',
        'publicKey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'privateKey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
    ),
);

$webPush = new WebPush($auth);

$res = $webPush->sendNotification(
    "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "hello",
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",     
    true    
);
```

Comment: Doing (almost) anything 100000 times will be a load on a server. I would suggest to buy more server-power. Apart from this: What exactly is your question? Thanks for the link to the web push library.

Comment: @KIKO: above code is sending push one by one so i need to call FCM api 1 lac time. i want send push to 1000 users at a time so that if i have 1 lac users then i need to call https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send API only 100 times as each push call send message to 1000 users.

Comment: So you question is: "How can I send a message to multiple user using only one API call?". I'm sorry, I don't know anything about Google's cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Webpush notifications can consume network and CPU resources, but optimizing your implementation can help. Upgrade to the latest library version (4.x), increase memory limit to 500MB, decrease timeout to 6 seconds, and disable SSL verify. These adjustments can potentially allow you to send around 500 webpushes within 5-7 seconds. However, for higher throughput like sending 1 million webpushes per minute, advanced optimizations and utilizing multiple servers would be necessary.

```
$push = new WebPush($authenticationData,[],6,['verify'=>false]);
ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');
```

If you have thousands of customers and want to send webpushes so fast I recommend you to send it without payload and you can get payload in service worker. In this way you can send 1000 webpush in under a second and it's gonna be so fast.

Sending webpushes with payload (to many users) spends so much cpu, ram and network resources. (Because library has to encrypt payload for each subscriber and has to send one by one to each subscriber. There is no bulk sending option for webpush with payload.)